# What's the code for dropping or deleting a table in arcpy?

Tags: python, sql, arcgis, arcpy

This should be really easy to lookup, but I've been searching for a good while and haven't been able to find it anywhere. I haven't even been able to find it on stackoverflow.

I do know that `arcpy.Delete_management` doesn't delete tables. That's about it.

Comment: I just tested and arcpy.Delete_management worked fine for me. Is your table in a file geodatabase?

Comment: @Evan it is, but this still isn't working. Is there another way?

Comment: Can you share the code you're trying? Have you tested on other tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esri's documentation indicates that you can use [Delete (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000052000000) to delete tables.

> Data Element; Graph; Layer; Table View

For example, the following shows a tested method to delete .csv, .dbf, and FGDB tables.

```
import arcpy

# A list of .dbf, .csv, and FGDB tables
tables = [r'C:\path\to\your.gdb\fgdb_table',
          r'C:\path\to\your\csv_table.csv',
          r'C:\path\to\your\dbf_table.dbf']

# Perform the deletion
for table in tables:
    arcpy.Delete_management(table)
```